# Oracle CLOB column and LAG

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm facing a problem when I try to use `LAG` function on `CLOB` column.

So let's assume we have a table

```
create table test (
    id number primary key, 
    not_clob varchar2(255),
    this_is_clob clob
);

insert into test values (1, 'test1', to_clob('clob1'));
insert into test values (2, 'test2', to_clob('clob2'));

DECLARE
x CLOB := 'C';
BEGIN

 FOR i in 1..32767
 LOOP
  x := x||'C';
 END LOOP;

 INSERT INTO test(id,not_clob,this_is_clob) values(3,'test3',x);

END;
/

commit;
```

Now let's do a select using non-clob columns

```
select id, lag(not_clob) over (order by id) from test;
```

It works fine as expected, but when I try the same with clob column

```
select id, lag(this_is_clob) over (order by id) from test;
```

I get

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 16
```

Can you tell me what's the solution of this problem as I couldn't find anything on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says the argument for any analytic function can be any datatype but it seems unrestricted CLOB is not supported.

However, there is a workaround:

```
select id, lag(dbms_lob.substr(this_is_clob, 4000, 1)) over (order by id) 
from test;
```

This is not the whole CLOB but 4k should be good enough in many cases.

> I'm still wondering what is the proper way to overcome the problem

Is upgrading to 12c an option? The problem is nothing to do with CLOB as such, it's the fact that Oracle has a hard limit for strings in SQL of 4000 characters. In 12c we have the option to use extended data types (providing we can persuade our DBAs to turn it on!). [Find out more.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/extended-data-types-12cR1#using-extended-data-types)

Comment: Thanks, this works really good. I also couldn't find anything on limitations regarding LOB columns in documentation.

Comment: @Alexey : This does not work when `this_is_clob` > 4000 characters. 32767 is the  `VARCHAR2` limit for PL/SQL in 11g and on certain settings in 12c and above for sql, but not in 11g. But the SQL limit is 4000 and `dbms_lob.substr` returns `VARCHAR2`  for CLOB input. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d73369e800e4a2848fb07197b6c8c0f9

Comment: @KaushikNayak Hm, actually you're right. Though at least we can change `dbms_lob.substr(this_is_clob, 32767, 1)` to `dbms_lob.substr(this_is_clob, 4000, 1)` (with `to_char` we'll always get an exception when column length exceeds 4000)

Comment: It's better than nothing, though I'm still wondering what is the proper way to overcome the problem

Comment: @APC Unfortunately migrating to 12c isn't an option :( Thanks for the explanation anyway. At least now I can understand why it happens

Answer (score 1):

Some of the features may not work properly in SQL when using `CLOBs`(like `DISTINCT` , `ORDER BY` `GROUP BY` etc. Looks like `LAG` is also one of them but, I couldn't find anywhere in docs.

If your values in the `CLOB` columns are always less than 4000 characters, you may use  `TO_CHAR`

```
select id, lag( TO_CHAR(this_is_clob)) over (order by id) from test;
```

OR

convert it into an equivalent `SELF JOIN` ( may not be as efficient as `LAG` )

```
SELECT a.id,
       b.this_is_clob AS lagging
FROM test a
LEFT JOIN test b ON b.id < a.id;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4e7f410ecc05cedf848d492155d6c8cc)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, self join isn't a full replacement when you need more than one previous row (you have to do more than one self join in that case as in the original table order of ids isn't that obvious).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I think I found an answer which eliminates the need to restrict the CLOB length and wanted to share it.  Utilizing CTE and recursive subqueries, we can replicate the lag functionality with CLOB columns.

First, let's take a look at my "original" query:

```sql
WITH TEST_TABLE AS
(
 SELECT LEVEL ORDER_BY_COL,
        TO_CLOB(LEVEL) AS CLOB_COL
 FROM DUAL
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
)
SELECT tt.order_by_col,
       tt.clob_col,
       LAG(tt.clob_col) OVER (ORDER BY tt.order_by_col)
FROM test_table tt;
```

As expected, I get the following error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Now, lets look at the modified query:

```sql
WITH TEST_TABLE AS
(
 SELECT LEVEL ORDER_BY_COL,
        TO_CLOB(LEVEL) AS CLOB_COL
 FROM DUAL
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
),
initial_pull AS
(
  SELECT tt.order_by_col,
         LAG(tt.order_by_col) OVER (ORDER BY tt.order_by_col) AS PREV_ROW,
         tt.clob_col
  FROM test_table tt
),
recursive_subquery (order_by_col, prev_row, clob_col, prev_clob_col) AS
(
  SELECT ip.order_by_col, ip.prev_row, ip.clob_col, NULL
  FROM initial_pull ip
  WHERE ip.prev_row IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ip.order_by_col, ip.prev_row, ip.clob_col, rs.clob_col
  FROM initial_pull ip
  INNER JOIN recursive_subquery rs ON ip.prev_row = rs.order_by_col
)
SELECT rs.order_by_col, rs.clob_col, rs.prev_clob_col
FROM recursive_subquery rs;
```

So here is how it works.

1. I create the TEST_TABLE, this really is only for the example as you should already have this table somewhere in your schema.
2. I create a CTE of the data I want to pull, plus a LAG function on the primary key (or a unique column) in the table partitioned and ordered in the same way I would have in my original query.
3. Create a recursive subquery using the initial row as the root and descending row by row joining on the lagged column.  Returning both the CLOB column from the current row and the CLOB column from its parent row.